# Building a home router on a laptop

Tags: networking, router, pfsense

I am in a process of building a router and PFSense based firewall on a laptop. 
My trouble is that I need an additional Ethernet port. I've come across "USB to Ethernet converter module", which is reasonably priced.

My question is, can I use my existing Ethernet port on my laptop as `eth0` and use the converted port as `eth1`?

Comment: I've not previously use PFSense, although I plan to, but I have made a router out of a laptop before using the wireless and wired interfaces with iptables. I don't see why PF, which I'm guessing is more powerful, would not be able route packets from the built in iface to the addition usb one - and vise versa.

Answer (score 0):

Many such adapters are compatible with linux. The specific one your looking at could be compatible or might have issues.  The key is to have the newest version of the linux kernel as possible.  Most drivers are built into the kernel as modules.  Every new version of the kernel improves it.  The current version as of 3-22-2014 is 3.13.6